# Как подключить ещё один ip к vps ubuntu 18?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет, как подключить к vps ещё один айпи, я делаю по инструкции через netplan, но почему-то новый ip не добавляется, у меня есть только сам ipv4, подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 185.233.116.108/22
        - 2a0c:c80:0:746c::2/64
      gateway4: 185.112.116.1
      gateway6: "1a0c:0c70:0000:746c::1"
      nameservers:
        addresses: [91.206.200.6, 91.222.139.6]
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 185.111.11.11/22
      gateway4: 185.111.11.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [91.206.200.6, 91.222.139.6]
```

Comment: а как вы определили, что «не добавляется»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin через ifconfig

Comment: нда. [двадцать лет уж прошло](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712), а мифы про то, что ifconfig подходит для диагностики, всё живы. // 1. вам адреса точно нужны на разных интерфейсах? 2. что именно вы проделывали после изменения `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`? 3. вы уверены, что network manager у вас обращает внимание на netplan вообще и его конфигруацию в частности? 4. в логах смотрели на предмет информации о сетевых настройках? // стоит всё-таки приложить вывод `$ ip a; ip r` до и после попыток изменеия конфигурации сетевых интерфейсов.

Comment: откуда у вас eth1 на vps?

Comment: @eri я добавил сам

Comment: Вы хозяин vps? или как вы его добавили?

Comment: @eri на хостинге есть возможность докупить для vps ещё ip

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin подскажите пожалуйста туториал по этому, я делал всё как в документации хоста на котором vps взял, но ничего не сработало

Comment: `$ man netplan`. если вас именно netplan интересует.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ещё раз переспрошу если можно) Мне нужно чтобы запросы по двум ip обрабатывались на одном сервере, сам айпи как мне сказали привязан к серверу мне его нужно только настроить

Comment: вы уверены, что до начала всех этих ваших манипуляций запросы ко второму ip **не обрабатывались** вашим сервером?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ответили так, может я не правильно понимаю? 
Он привязан к серверу на уровне ноды, на которой размещаются виртуальный сервера, но не настроен на самом сервере - об этом речь

Comment: из внешнего мира на, например, ping-и, отвечают оба ip-адреса?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin второй не отвечает. Ответ от 185.222.111.133: Заданный узел недоступен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129634/discussion-between-aleksandr-barakin-and-oleksandr).